# Delete rows based on range possible mistake

Tags: vba, excel, range, rows, delete-row

I'm trying to delete rows on one worksheet based on a range in another worksheet. I think the problem here is probably something simple based on my limited VBA experience.  Here is the code I've written:

```
Sub LimitedElements()

imax = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 2 To imax
    If Sheets("test").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Limited Elements").Range("A1:A10") Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I get a message saying "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or if this is just a dumb way to do this and I should be doing it differently?

Comment: you must decrement 'i' after you delete row or you may skip some rows

Comment: I'd advise you to loop through your range backwards when deleting (For i = imax to 2 step -1) or you very well will end up with unexpected results.

Comment: You were right about looping backwards. My new code seemed to be running continuously until changed the direction. I'm going to have to think about why that was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if below works for you:

```
Sub LimitedElements()  
Dim imax As Integer  
Dim a As Variant  
Dim b As Range  
Dim c As Object  
Dim d As Integer  

imax = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 2 To imax  
a = Sheets("test").Cells(i, 1).Value  
Set b = Sheets("Limited Elements").Range("A1:A10")  
Set c = b.Find(What:=a, LookIn:=xlValues)  

If Not c Is Nothing Then  
    Sheets("test").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete  
    i = i - 1  
    imax = imax - 1  
    End If  
Next i  
End Sub
```

Noted that it is not fine tuned and is intended to give you an understanding on how to approach the solution.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I'm sure I can make work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I added code to decrement i. I think I understand that the code can't tell which worksheet I'm specifying for deleting the row but I'm not sure what to do about it. I tried changing "Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete" to "Sheets("test").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete" but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do or not.

Some extra details to make things clearer:

Sheet "test" has about 1000 rows with unique numbers in column A. Sheet "Limited Elements" has about 100 rows with unique numbers column A. I want it it delete the rows in "test" that have values in column A that match the column A values in "Limited Elements".

```
Sub LimitedElements()
imax = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 2 To imax

    If Sheets("test").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Limited Elements").Range("A1:A10") Then
    Sheets("test").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
    imax = imax - 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I think the original problem was that I had Cells(j,1) instead of cells(i,1). Now I've fixed that but it gives me a type mismatch error which I think is due to comparing a single cell to a range.

At this point I think I'm just lost. I can't figure out how to change it so it works and does what I want it to do.

Comment: See my comment in your question.  It's a cleaner approach than modifying variables within the loop (IMO).